# Duplicate entry for primary key - registration form

Tags: java, mysql

I have one simple registraton form with jsp, servlet and mysql. But, I can register only one user, then i got this error:

`Severe:   Message: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`. Of course, when I delete that user from database I can create again but just one user. Also, I put auto increment on that column:

`CREATE TABLE user (id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ...`

This is also my method for insert in db:

```
public class UserDAO {

public int registerUser(User User) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO user"
            + "  (id, firstName, lastName, username, password, email) VALUES "
            + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    int result = 0;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cs230projekat","root","");
            // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL)) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, User.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, User.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, User.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, User.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, User.getEmail());

        System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
        result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // process sql exception
        printSQLException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think that `1` is a good `id` value for all your users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always setting the value of your `id` column to 1 via `preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1)`. Since you say you have an auto-increment on the `id` column, remove `id` from your SQL, remove the aforementioned line and adjust the column indexes (first arguments) for all the other `setString()` method calls.

Comment: But then I won't have a user ID

Comment: You don’t need the ID if you have the “auto increment” set for that field.  With that feature set any insert into that table doesn’t need you to explicitly set that.  MySQL DB will automatically increment the id to the next value, hence the feature name “auto increment”

Comment: The purpose of AUTO_INCREMENT is to generate one for you. In MySQL you can retrieve it by calling the function LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: Yes, it works now but I don't have the primary key in the database.

Comment: I want to have one ID in the database with a primary key that will increase each time a new user registers.

Answer (score 1):

With auto increment set you don’t have to specify the ‘id’ column in your sql insert statements.

Here’s some information on the auto increment from MySQL’s website: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you are inserting the value 1 always for the id column, try implementing the autoGenerate properly. For more help, you can have a look on similar [implementation](https://www.technicalkeeda.com/jdbc-tutorials/how-to-get-mysql-auto-increment-key-value-using-java-jdbc)